# Remove lines with long TLD (Top Level Domain)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, domain-name

Is there a more efficient way of removing lines with a invalid / too long of a tld (Top Level Domain)? I'm not efficient with sed / awk. I'm wanting to remove lines from a file that are longer than 24 characters, after the last period.

What I wrote works, but is extremely slow on long lists. It takes each individual line, counts the number of characters after the period, saves the lines with more than 24 characters to a list, then removes them from the source.

Sample Input:

```
test.sub.xn--vermgensberatung-pwb
test.sub.xn--vermgensberatung-pwba
```

Expected Output:

```
test.sub.xn--vermgensberatung-pwb
```

My current code:

```
Source='/tmp/source'

while read -r Line || [[ -n "$Line" ]]; do
count="$(echo "$Line" | awk -F. '{ print $NF }' | awk '{ print length }')" #Count length after period
if [[ "$count" -gt '24' ]]; then echo "$Line" >> /tmp/filter; fi           #Save long TLD lines
done < "$Source"

#Remove results from source
cat /tmp/filter | sort > /tmp/filter.clean
comm -23 "$Source" /tmp/filter.clean > /tmp/clean
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the public suffix list instead of just trying to restrict by length?

Comment: When posting sample input/output, don't post 1 line under a header that says `Keep` and a separate line under a header that says `Remove` - make it simple for us to understand and test with and just post a single block of input lines and a single file of the expected output lines given that input. I updated your question to show what I mean.

Comment: The examples you gave with `xn--` as prefix are NOT invalid TLDs. They are IDNs. Whatever you do, do not put length restrictions on labels, this makes no sense.

Comment: @Mevzek - What would be the best method for removing invalid TLDs from a list - 1mil+ lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you over-complicate the script

```
$ cat file
www.cnn.com
this.is.notrightbutstillpass
this.will.fail.since.01234567890123456789012345
```

not sure the actual TLD restrictions but you can change the code easily

```
$ awk -F. 'length($NF)<24' file
www.cnn.com
this.is.notrightbutstillpass
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for:

```
$ grep -Ev '\.[^.]{25,}$' file
test.sub.xn--vermgensberatung-pwb
```

To update the original file without manually creating a temp file you could use GNU sed instead of grep:

```
sed -Ei '/\.[^.]{25,}$/d' file
```

Comment: I fixed it. Going forward if/when you ask new questions please remember to include sample input/output in your question so we have something to test with.